# Get all products without image using rest API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to get all the simple products that do not have a product image assigned using the rest API?

What I would like is a product list with skus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [searchCriteria](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html)

Example:

```
/rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku]  
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=image  
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=no_selection  
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq  
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=type_id  
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq  
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=simple
```

Be careful with copy and pasting. Correct format:

```
/rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku]&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=image&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=no_selection&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=type_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=simple
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. returns 0 products.